# htmlpurifier producing error 'Fatal error: Class 'HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform_BdoDir' not found' but my paths are correct

Tags: php, security, xss, htmlpurifier

I must be missing something or I had way to much coffee because I cannot figure out for the life of me why this is not working.

```
$dirty_html = "<p>test</p>";
require_once 'this/is/my/path/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
echo $clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
```

I have checked the path so many times and it is correct but for some reason I get

```
Fatal error: Class 'HTMLPurifier_AttrTransform_BdoDir' not found in /home/me/public_html/website/this/is/my/path/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier/HTMLModule/Bdo.php on line 38
```

Both my relative path used in `require_once` and the absolute path shown by the error are correct. What am I not seeing?

**SOLVED**

So after uploading it several times and still having the same issue I decided to change my upload method with (Filezilla) to passive and it worked fine. Really random but it worked so sorry for the useless post. I would have tried it earlier first, but I have been uploading with FZ for years without any issues so I never even thought of changing it to passive.

Comment: What version of HTMLPurifier are you using? Are you using Composer to load it in? (If not, it's highly recommended that you do. Then you can just load `vendor/autoload.php` and these problems magically disappear.)

Comment: Random solution but I finally had to change Filezilla to upload as passive and it worked fine so it seemed to be more a corruption issue with the files. No idea why it worked, but it did.

Comment: In my experience, FTP software has generally been unreliable. Get SSH access and use SCP instead. Better security, better reliability, and you're one step away from `rsync`.